# Regex help - match any number of characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have following kind of string-sets in a text file:

```
<< /ImageType 1
/Width 986 /Height 1
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1]
/ImageMatrix [986 0 0 -1 0 1]
/DataSource <
803fe0503824160d0784426150b864361d0f8844625138a4562d178c466351b8e4763d1f904864523924964d27944a6552b964b65d2f984c665339a4d66d379c4e6753b9e4f67d3fa05068543a25168d47a4526954ba648202
> /LZWDecode filter >> image } def
```

There are 100s of Images defined like above.

I need to find all such images defined in the document.
Here is my code -

```
string txtFile = @"text file path";
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(txtFile);

string pattern = @"<< /ImageType 1.*(\n|\r|\r\n)*image } def"; //match any number of characters between `<< /ImageType 1` and `image } def`
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(fileContents, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
int count = matchCollection.Count; // returns 1
```

However, I am getting just one match - whereas there are around 600 images defined.
But it seems they all are matched in one because of 'newline' character used in pattern.

Can anyone please guide what do I need to modify the correct result of regex match as 600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that regular expressions are usually greedy, i.e. the matches are always as long as possible. Thus, the `image } def` is contained in the `.*`. I think the best approach here would be to perform two separate regex queries, one for `<< /ImageType 1` and one for `image } def`. Every match of the first pattern would correspond to exactly one match of the second one and as these matches carry their indices in the original string, you can reconstruct the image by accessing the appropriate substring.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.*` you should use the non-greedy quantifier `.*?`:

```
string pattern = @"<< /ImageType 1.*?image } def";
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a site that can help you out with REGEX that I use. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php.

```
if(preg_match('/^/[a-z]/i', $string, $matches)){

 echo "Match was found <br />";
 echo $matches[0];
}
```